# Laravel 9 - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-9, mailtrap

The issue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "b926ad2c64b4a7" using the following authenticators: "CRAM-MD5", "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "CRAM-MD5" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "451", with message "451 4.3.2 Internal server error".". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "334" but got empty code.". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got empty code.".

My Laravel Project was all working perfectly fine a few days ago. (No Code Changes have been made). When I stumbled into the error I updated my SMPT setting within the .env file like so:

**.env**

```
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=b926ad2c64b4a7
    MAIL_PASSWORD=ba6651bbf8xxxx
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

with the new setting's in place within the .env file, I'm still receiving the same error. I use npm run dev (Laravel Vite) and Docker Container.  Shut down the laravel vite and for docker I have used docker compose down and then docker compose up for complete refresh. same error still happens.

**Ran following**

```
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: mailtrap has some limit on how many emails you can send through an account, perhaps you can try and create new mailtrap account? or try use mailhog for mail testing

Comment: Same error from different user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028357/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username-d0234aa6969603-using-3-pos

Comment: @Win, Ah okay that makes sense. I try'd again this morning and the emails are working fine again. Looks like the issue was probably the limit of emails being sent. 
Furthermore, I did end up creating a second mailtrap account yesterday to see if the error persisted and the error still persisted.

Comment: ok , I just try it myself and it works fine, I guess there is some trouble from mailtrap end for some users, but there is not information on their site or twitter on this matter, i recommend use other smtp service or use mailhog

Comment: i also got the same error.do you find any solution ??