# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "d0234aa6969603" using 3 possible authenticators. using laravel 8

Tags: laravel, mailtrap

I am using mailtrap.io for sending emails i am trying to send emails but unfortunatly i am getting error please help me how can i resolved that thank u.

please check error. https://flareapp.io/share/Rmr2ZAqm

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=d0234aa6969603
MAIL_PASSWORD=2d973b871e67d5
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Same error, different user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027727/laravel-9-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username

Comment: @UnderDog I guess there is some trouble from mailtrap, but there is not information on their site or twitter on this matter, i recommend use other smtp service or use mailhog